# adding new registered users to the database and their login system in django

Tags: django

i have created a form in which the user enters data and that data is saved onto the database.but the form is not s![enter image description here][1]aving the data is there any wrong in the coding?please help..

my code is here:-

```
1) views.py 
-----------------------------------------------------------
from django.http import  HttpResponse
#from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from forms import SignupForm

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.cleaned_data('username')
            form.cleaned_data('email')
            form.cleaned_data('password1')
            form.save()
        return HttpResponse('/login/')     #havent did the login method yet...
    else: 
        t = loader.get_template('signup.html')
        cform = SignupForm()
        c = RequestContext (request, {'form' : cform,})
        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))      

#def login(request):
#   newform = SignupForm()
#if newform.is_valid():
```

### 2) forms.py-

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    username            = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label="Username")
    email               = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label="E-Mail Address")
    password1           = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2           = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label="Repeat Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)


    def clean_username(self):
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']
        raise forms.ValidationError("This username is already in use.Please choose another.")

    def clean(self):
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError("You must type the same password each time")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self):
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=self.cleaned_data['username'], email=self.cleaned_data['email'], password=self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        return new_user
```

### 3)urls.py:-

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
#from salary import settings 
#from salarylive.views import signup
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    #url(r'^$', 'salary.views.home', name='home'),
    #url(r'^salary/', include('salary.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^signup/$', 'salarylive.views.signup'),
    #url(r'^login/$', 'salarylive.views.login'),
)
```

---

error traceback :-

```
error traceback :- Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/signup/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'salarylive')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "e:\Software Installations\Aptana Workspace\salary\salarylive\views.py" in signup
  10.             form.cleaned_data('username')

Exception Type: TypeError at /signup/
Exception Value: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some indentation errors. The first `return HttpResponse` should be indented one additional level, so that it only happens if the form is valid. The second `return HttpResponse` and the line above it should be indented one **less** level, so that it catches the fall-through from the if statement.

The way you have it, the code always redirects, even if the form is not valid and the data is not saved. With those changes, the second return will re-render the form with errors when it is not valid.

Comment: its showing me some error.. like  'dict' object is not callable      form.cleaned_data('username') ....

Comment: Sigh. I can't help you unless you say what the error actually is, and show the traceback.

Comment: please give me some reputation points so that i can upload picture of the error..

Comment: Because the syntax for accessing dictionary elements is square brackets, not round ones.

Comment: should be a list right not a tuple? yeah that executed sucessfully thank for the help buddy !!!

Comment: Neither, it's a dict, which you access with [] - eg `form.cleaned_data['username']`